# Type Mismatch Error in DLOOKUP Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Type mismatch erro in below code where unit,primepro and subpro datatypes are given as 'TEXT'

```
  Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()
If (Me.Status.Value = "COMPLETED") Then
Me.Combo35.Value = DLookup("Unit", "Units", "PrimePro='" & Me.Combo33.Value & "' And "SubPro='" & Me.Subact.Value & "'")

End If
End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: This "' And "SubPro='"  needs to change to "' And " & """ & "SupPro="

Comment: As you mentioned i have done the changes but It is showing syntax error(Missing Operator) in query expression------Me.Combo35.Value = DLookup("Unit", "Units", "PrimePro= '" & Me.Combo33.Value & "' And" & "''" & "SubPro= '" & Me.Subact.Value & "'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, you need to concatenate the String values. They need to be enclosed within single quotes. I have also removed `.Value` as this becomes redundant.

One final suggestion is that you add an Else part to the **AfterUpdate** event. When the value is `Complete` you need something, but what happens when it is `Not Completed`? Does the value still hold?

```
Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Status = "COMPLETED" Then
        Me.Combo35 = DLookup("Unit", "Units", "PrimePro = '" & Me.Combo33 & "' And SubPro = '" & Me.Subact & "'")
    'Else
        'Should do something, or the value will be irrelevant to the Status.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: At PaulFrancis, I have tried as you said but still i am getting same error

Comment: That would the case if `PrimePro` and/or `SubPro` are actually number fields and not Text in the table.

Comment: At Paul Francis, Thank you so much for the help. I found out where i am going wrong. Actually, The formula is correct but the data which i provided in the values is wrong so it is showing null values.

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

DLOOKUP is not Excel; it is Access. The WHERE clause should be:

```
"PrimePro='" & Me.Combo33.Value & "' And SubPro='" & Me.Subact.Value & "'"
```

(a quote before `SubPro=` too many).